# Error: FormatException was unhandled by user code in Linq how to solve?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, linq, entity-framework, c#-3.0

[image]

Look please below this codes throw me : FormatException was unhandled by user code

Codes:

```
 satis.KDV = Decimal.Parse((from o in genSatisctx.Urun where o.ID == UrunID select o.Kdv).ToString());
```

How can i rewrite linq query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling `ToString` on the query rather than a single result. Even though you may expect only one value to match your query, it will not return just a single value. You have to instruct it to do so using [`Single`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb155325.aspx), [`First`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb291976.aspx), [`Last`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549138.aspx) or the variations of these that also return a default value ([`SingleOrDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342451.aspx), [`FirstOrDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482.aspx), [`LastOrDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.lastordefault.aspx)).

In order to avoid an exception, you could change it to use [`Decimal.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.tryparse.aspx) or you could change your code to use a default value if the LINQ query returns something that won't parse properly. I'd recommend the former or a combination.

Note that in the following example, I have added the call to [SingleOrDefault](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342451.aspx). This ensures that only one value is parsed, even if no value is found, and that if there are multiple results, we get an exception (i.e. it enforces that we get exactly zero or one result to the query).

```
decimal parsedValue;
if (Decimal.TryParse(
     genSatisctx
     .Urun
     .Where(o => o.ID == UrunID)
     .Select(o=>o.Kdv)
     .SingleOrDefault()
     .ToString(), out parsedValue))
{
   satis.KDV = parsedValue;
}
```

Comment: If no value is found, that will throw a NullPointerException on the ToString call.

Comment: @Jon: Doesn't that depend on what `o.Kdv` is? If it's a Decimal or some other number, wouldn't default just be 0?

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `ToString()` on an `IQueryable<T>` - what did you expect the string to be? It's very unlikely to be anything which can be parsed as a decimal number!

My guess is that you want to call `First()` or `Single()`, but we can't really tell without more information. What's the type of `o.Kdv`?

I suspect you either want:

```
satis.KDV = (from o in genSatisctx.Urun 
             where o.ID == UrunID 
             select o.Kdv).First();
```

or

```
string kdvString = (from o in genSatisctx.Urun 
                    where o.ID == UrunID 
                    select o.Kdv).First();
decimal kdv;
if (decimal.TryParse(kdvString, out kdv))
{
    satis.KDV = kdv;
}
else
{
    // What do you want to do if it's not valid?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When I use debug mode I see the data is update when over mouse, after end of this method ( it's show this message [input string was not in a correct format]

```
 /*   protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
           try
          {

            TextBox name = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtEditName");
            SqlDataSource2.UpdateParameters["Name"].DefaultValue = name.ToString();

            TextBox age = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtEditAge");
            SqlDataSource2.UpdateParameters["Age"].DefaultValue = age.ToString();

            TextBox birthday = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtEditBirthday");
            SqlDataSource2.UpdateParameters["Birthday"].DefaultValue = birthday.ToString();

            DropDownList country = (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("DropEditCountry");
            SqlDataSource2.UpdateParameters["CountryID"].DefaultValue = country.SelectedValue;


            TextBox mobile = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtEditMobile");
            SqlDataSource2.UpdateParameters["Mobile_No"].DefaultValue = mobile.ToString();
            SqlDataSource2.Update();
        }
        catch (Exception j)
       {
       j.Message.ToString();
       }
    }

/* }
```

Comment: You need to [edit] and fix your formatting, otherwise you're going to get downvoted and you won't get any answers.